# KODI Remote control using LIRC worked and now doesn't

Tags: kodi, lirc

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Kodi 15.02.  I have a Sony MCE RC6 type remote control, so I installed LIRC, configured for Windows Media remote control, tested it with IRW, and it worked.  KODI then worked wonderfully with full remote.  After I rebooted the PC, it didn't work!  I tested with IRW and got nothing.   I tried removing LIRC and re-installing and it still doesn't work.  I searched forums and tried about 6 different things, but it still doesn't work anymore.  It's driving me nuts.  What has gone wrong?  Can anyone make any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recent experience with Lubuntu 16.04.1 and an MCE RC6 remote.  Without even installing lirc, the remote behaves like a keyboard -- but not all of the keys on the remote work.

Using the remote with the application "Mythtv", most of the functions that I need worked without any changes (without installing lirc). But, using the regular keyboard, all of the functions are available (Mythtv can be controlled without a remote, just using the keyboard).  So, to make additional keys on the remote work (or customize remote key functions) I am using the package "ir-keytable".  This allows you to easily map keys on the remote to keyboard keys.

There are other approaches, but I was not able to make them work. For example, I was not able to get anywhere using lirc, or using udev to remap scancodes from the remote to keysyms. (On previous versions of linux, I did use lirc).